# Write/read bit-string to/from a file

Tags: python, string, file, bitstring

I've encoded an 8x8 block of numbers using RLE and got this string of bits that I need to write to a file. The last coefficient of the sequence is padded accordingly so that the whole thing is divisible by 8.

[image: encoded coefficients]

In the image above, you can see the array of numbers, the RLE encoding(86 bits long), the padded version so its divisible by 8 (88 bits long) and the concatenated string that I am to write to a file.

```
0000110010001100110110111100001000111011001100010000111101111000011000110011101000100011
```

Would the best way to write this concatenated string be to divide the thing into 8 bit long substrings and write those individually as bytes or is there a simpler, faster way to do this? When it comes to binary data, the only module I've worked with so far is `struct`, this is the first time i've tackled something like this. Any and all advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `struct` is a good std lib choice.  For a higher level 3rd-party option consider [`bitstring`](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert it to a list using regex.

```
import re
file = open(r"insert file path here", "a")


bitstring = "0000110010001100110110111100001000111011001100010000111101111000011000110011101000100011"

bitlist = re.findall('........', bitstring) #seperates bitstring into a list of each item being 8 characters long

for i in range(len(bitlist)):
    file.write(bitlist[i])
    file.write("\n")
```

Let me know if this is what you mean.

I would also like to mention how pulling data from a text file will not be the most efficient way of store it. The fastest would ideally be kept in an array such as [["10110100"], ["00101010"]] and pull the data by doing...

```
bitarray = [["10110100"], ["00101010"]]

>>> print(bitarray[0][0])
10110100
```